# NameError: name 'width' is not definedd

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

kam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
foto = cv2.imread('resim.jpg')
def foto_cevirme(fotogir):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(fotogir,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    fotogir = cv2.blur(fotogir,(3,3))


    lower_red = np.array([0,120,70])

    upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])

    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
  

    lower_red = np.array([170,120,70])

    upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])

    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_red,upper_red)


    mask1 = mask1+mask2
    (contours,hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(mask1.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for c in contours:
      if cv2.contourArea(c) < 500:
        continue
      (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
      cv2.rectangle(fotogir,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),3)
      global face_width 
      face_width = w
    return face_width

    res1 = cv2.bitwise_and(fotogir,fotogir,mask=mask1)
    cv2.imshow("foto",fotogir)

known_distance = 40  # kameraya uzaklik
known_width = 20   # yüzünüzün ortalam genisligi

def focal_length(measured_distance, real_width, width_in_rf_image):
   focal_length = (width_in_rf_image * measured_distance)/ real_width
   return focal_length

def distance_finder(Focal_length,real_face_width,face_width_in_frame):
   distance = (real_face_width* Focal_length)/ face_width_in_frame 
   return distance


fotokare = foto_cevirme(foto) 
ref_image_face_width = fotokare
focal_length_found = focal_length(known_distance,known_width,ref_image_face_width)
fonts = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX


while True:
  
  ret, goruntu = kam.read()


  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(goruntu,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

  goruntu = cv2.blur(goruntu,(8,8))


  lower_red = np.array([0,120,70])

  upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])

  mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)


  lower_red = np.array([170,120,70])

  upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])

  mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_red,upper_red)


  mask1 = mask1+mask2
  (contours,hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(mask1.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


  for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 500:
      continue
    else:
      exit
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    genislik = w
  

  Distance = distance_finder(focal_length_found,known_width,genislik)
  cv2.putText(goruntu,f"Uzaklik = {Distance}",(50,50),fonts,1,(0,0,255),2)

  res1 = cv2.bitwise_and(goruntu,goruntu,mask=mask1)

  cv2.imshow("orj",goruntu)

  cv2.imshow("mask",mask1)
  cv2.imshow("res",res1)
  
  
  if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
    

kam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hello ı am trying to color detection and distance program,but when ı was trying to define w (width) its giving me a genislik is not defined ? why

Comment: This comment is not addressing your issue but i wanted to share. In your function `foto_cevirme(fotogir)`, you have a return statement. There are 2 statements after that. It will NEVER get executed as the code already reached return statement

Comment: The for loop before `  Distance = distance_finder(focal_length_found,known_width,genislik)` is a bit tricky. If all values of c result in `< 500`, then `genislik` will not be defined. If it is greater than or equal to 500, you are asking it to exit. The code `(x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)` and `genislik = w` is never executed. So when it reaches `Distance`, then you have a variable that's not defined

Comment: Thank you for your comments I understand the problems  but  stillı dont how to fix this problem

Comment: Set a default value for `genislik`

Comment: What I am saying is, the code you posted has "dead code" that will NOT execute. You are assuming that the portion of the 'dead code' will get executed. Some portion of your code is considering those. You need to address them to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to explain this using the comments section. Let me share the screenshot to explain.

You need to solve for the variable `genislik` by assigning a default value. The code inside for loop never gets executed.

The `exit` command in your code will actually exit the program not just the loop. I assume you were trying to break out of the loop. In the image `exit` actually cancels the program. Change it to `break` instead.

[image]

You have a similar challenge here as well. You need to have a default value set for `face_width` otherwise, it will give you an error stating `face_width` is not defined.

[image]